# Working with C string livehack needed

Tags: c, string

I have function, that logs string info:

```
void Log(const char *aValue, int logLevel)
{
...
}
```

Very often I need to log text info that consists of several strings. In C I see only one way of doing that - create string variable, sprintf both phrases to that variable, log variable like:

```
 #define VERSION "1.1.1"

 char s [256] ;
 sprintf(s,"%s %s","starting programm ",VERSION);
 Log(s,INFO);
```

This is such a big job when you need to print just 2 concatenated strings! Is it possible to make something like in other languages do:

```
Log("starting programm "+VERSION, INFO)
```

?

Comment: how about a var arg function? http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson17.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change your `Log` function to use `vsnprintf`:

```
#include <stdarg.h>
int Log(int level, char const * fmt, ...)
{
    char buffer[256];
    int ret;
    va_list args;   
    va_start(args, fmt);
    ret = vsnprintf(buffer, 256, fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
    /* write log output here */
    return ret;
}

Log(INFO, "Starting program %s", VERSION);
```

If having constant 256 character buffer size is not enough, you could modify it to use malloc or VLAs (variable length arrays).

**Edit:**

If your output is going to end up in file, you could use `vfprintf` instead and avoid having to mess with buffer size.

Answer (score 7):

If `VERSION` is a preprocessor constant expanding to a literal string, then you can concatenate them simply by placing them together:

```
Log("starting program " VERSION, INFO)
```